# MVC Databinding in C#

Tags: c#, windows, model-view-controller

I'm working on a Project with MVC and Windows Form. I will use database data for the Application. But because I use MVC I must separate Model, View and Controller.

When I use the data binding Option on the Windows Form I use business logic in the view, doesn't I?

How can I use this databinding on the Windowsform concurring MVC?

Comment: Show us your Code please.

Comment: I don't have Code alreay. I'm Brainstorming. I don't know how I could use this databinding without violate the MVC structure.

Comment: That's not really the purpose of StackOverflow. You should just try and do it, and if it doesn't work, come back with specific problems that we can try and help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a document about architecture that can help you about this

[Architecting Modern Web Applications with ASP.NET Core and Azure](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/aspnet-ebook)

Also we have a pattern called ViewModel, you can read more about in this link

[ViewModel Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx)

Comment: Links talk about either ASP or WPF, while the OP tells he uses WinForms.

Comment: I don't work with MVC ASP.NET. I will use WinForms. Is there any possibility to do it with MVC and not with MVVM?

Comment: The architecture can be applied to any kind of project

Comment: But when I have Data on the Form(View) it's not a clean MVC, isn't it?